# How to set up several separate python scrips to write to a single CSV file without IO errors

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to set up several separate python scrips to write to a single csv file, without inducing IO errors. The scrips are running in parallel, and every second or so write a new row. [they are getting data from separate servers, hence need to have them both running at the same time]

I haven't had a large number of errors so far [two scrips] however am guessing this is more 'luck' and if i were to scale it up with more parallel scrips I would start to run into more and more problems caused when the scrips attempt to write at the same time.

Is there a way of getting the scrips to wait until they are able to write to the file [i.e if there is a clash, to until the other scrip has finished writing], rather than just throwing up errors IO? [I am ideally looking for a solution which doesn't just skip instances when there is a problem, which I guess a try while set up would result in]

Comment: Instead of doing this the manual route and implementing the coordination yourself, why not use a file format (e.g. SQLite) that's designed to avoid such issues?

Comment: A common way to handle this is to have producer scripts put their data in a queue and have a separate consumer task which takes it off and writes stuff to the file. That way there won't be any I/O errors. Python has a [Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html?highlight=queue) module/class for multithreading, and [another one](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=queue#exchanging-objects-between-processes) which is part of its [`multiprocessing` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=queue#module-multiprocessing).